# Only get the subtotal of all the items

Tags: mysql, rollup

I'm trying to move the sum value to the right instead of it being on the bottom.

Currently, I have this query:

```
SELECT

if(product is NULL, 'Total', product) as Product,

total_items as Total,
SUM(total_items) as Subtotal
FROM items

WHERE inv = "ABC"


GROUP BY product
WITH ROLLUP
```

Output of this is:

```
|   Product     |   Total   |   Subtotal    |
|   AB          |   260     |   260         |
|   DE          |   66      |   66          |
|   Total       |   66      |   326         |
```

Is there a way I can do it like this?

```
|   Product     |   Total   |   Subtotal    |
|   AB          |   260     |               |
|   DE          |   66      |               |
|               |           |   326         |
```

Comment: why not do it outside of MySQL

Comment: Yeah - I'm not really a fan of rollup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, thank you for suggesting the union all.
I did it like this

```
SELECT

product,
total_items as Total,
null as Total

FROM items

WHERE inv = "ABC"

GROUP BY product

UNION ALL

SELECT null, null, Subtotal
FROM
(   SELECT

    if(product is NULL, 'Subtotal', product) as Product,
    SUM(total_items) as Subtotal

    FROM items

    WHERE inv = "ABC"


    GROUP BY product
    WITH ROLLUP
) T
WHERE product = "Subtotal"
```

Output:

```
|   Product     |   Total   |   Subtotal    |
|   AB          |   260     |               |
|   DE          |   66      |               |
|               |           |   326         |
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product,
       total_items,
       null as Subtotal
FROM items
WHERE inv = "ABC"
union all
select null, null, SUM(total_items) from items
```